# How to make a List items to select

Tags: html

I have a box in which i have displayed a list of cities, i want it to make  selectable so that user can select multiple cities.thanks in advance

my code is:

```
'<div class="box" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: -330px;">
<ul multiple="multiple" style="list-style-type: none;">
<li>mumbai</li>
<li>bangalore</li>
<li>hyderabad</li>
<li>chennai
</li>
</ul>'
```

Comment: Go to https://www.google.com and type in "selectable list html" or better yet "jQuery selectable"

Comment: I want the li to be selectable not the select option in html any way thank you very much Vali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a form item rather than a list if you want them selectable; like so:

```
<div class="box" style="display: inline-block;margin-left: -330px;">
<select multiple="multiple">
<option value="0">mumbai</option>
<option value="1">bangalore</option>
<option value="2">hyderabad</option>
<option value="3">chennai</option>
</select>
```

HTH;

Comment: Thanks for that, I know this approach I want to select the list in a box

Comment: you do know that doesn't have to be a dropdown eh? - can be a box; with a spot of css- like so: `select { height=300px;}` or actually: here how does this look: http://jsfiddle.net/NickWilde/vhtqK/1/